# Loopback component storage file upload from mobile devices/postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, loopbackjs, postman

How can I upload an image from post-man to the loopback component storage upload api. I have already setup the api and successfully uploaded to the storage through file upload from a form from my website, but I am not able to post it from postman. What should be the request body and headers for the same?

Answer (score 3):

Say you have base api root `http://myserver.com`

**To create a container** :

1) The url : `http://myserver.com/containers`

2) Request Header : `Content-Type : application/json`

3) Body (you can set it in **raw** tab) :

```
{
 "name": "my-container"
}
```

4) Method : `POST`

---

**To upload a file to container `my-container`**

1) The Url : `http://myserver.com/containers/my-container/upload`

2) Request Header : `Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

3) Body :  `form-data` (you choose the file in tab `form-data`)

> The `key` is not important. Even it can be empty.
>
> The `value` should be of type `file`.

When you choose value type of file, the file chooser appears and you can select the file.

4) Method : `POST`

Comment: I tried this way but it went on showing "Sending Request" and nothing happened. So I removed the content-type header and added "Accept: multipart/form-data" header. Then I got response as "Not Acceptable" but image was uploaded to the folder correctly. What could be wrong?

Comment: @DevStar Did you use the built-in api endpoints or you have made an endpoint wrapping them?

Comment: I have used the builtin api endpoint - container/{containername}/upload.

Comment: @DevStar I don't know. Maybe the full header requests and request payload helps. And the `Content-Type` is needed too

Comment: Ok, Thanks, I will check with content-type included. Meanwhile can you check this question too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42782033/rename-file-before-upload-using-remote-hooks-in-loopback-component-storage